# Filter and sort records from Hive box in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Im using Hive with Flutter to store contacts with key as alphanumeric string, each contact data is a map with timestamp in it

Box Rows =

```
Key.     => Value  
'abc123' => {'name': 'JK', 'country':'GB', 'timestamp': '568'},
'etergb' => {'name': 'FS', 'country':'DE', 'timestamp': '425'}
'546hfg' => {'name': 'TD', 'country':'GB', 'timestamp': '687'}
```

Now is it possible to filter these with **where country=GB** condition and sort the rows by map.item.timestamp ASC/DESC

Comment: so that value is a `List<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>` ? Or is the top level just the Map with keys like abc123.  What is it you want to reorder... Maps don't have a sort. :)

Comment: Hive doesn't yet support sorting and filtering natively. If you want to do this, you will have to manually do it yourself in code.

Answer (score 4):

**Filter**

```
final hiveBox = Hive.box<Dynamic>('<BOX_NAME>');
List values = hiveBox.values.toList();

filtered = box.values
  .where((object) => object['country'] == 'GB')
  .toList();
```

**Sort**

```
filtered.sort((a, b) => a['timestamp'].compareTo(b['timestamp']));
```

Answer (score 2):

For filtering, you can use For loop or Map.

You can perform the sort. Below is an example.

```
var items = box.values.toList();
items.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name)); //ASC
items.sort((b, a) => a.name.compareTo(b.name)); //DESC


@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class CategoryModel extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  String id;

  @HiveField(1)
  String name;

  //...
  
  CategoryModel(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: and how to sort in descending order ?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Or since compareTo returns an int, you could do 
items.sort((a, b) => -a.name.compareTo(b.name)); //DESC